# Преобразование 24 часа времени в 12 часов (PM / AM) времени

Tags: java, android, алгоритм

Необходимо преобразовать время из 12 – часового формата в 24-часовой формат, имеется строка вида 12 : 22 AM, а он парсит как 12 : 22 PM, вот сам код, не всегда парсит время правильно, в чем может быть проблема

вот пример кода где получаю время из программы

```
    String temp = DateTimesHelper.parse_AM_PM_Time(addTime.getText().toString());
           time = DateTimesHelper.parseStandartTime(temp, offset);
```

вот сами парсеры

```
    public static String parse_AM_PM_Time(String str) {
    //timeText = editTimeH.getText().toString() + ":" + editTimeM.getText().toString() + " " + editTime_AM.getText().toString() + " " + editTime_PM.getText().toString();
    String[] checkTime = str.replace(":"," ").trim().split(" ");
    String old_h = checkTime[0];
    String old_m = checkTime[1];
    String AM_PM = "";
    if (str.contains("AM")){
        AM_PM = "AM";
    }
    if (str.contains("PM")){
        AM_PM = "PM";
    }
    if(old_h.length() != 2){
        old_h = "0" + old_h;
    }
    if(old_m.length() != 2){
        old_m = "0" + old_m;
    }
    str = old_h + ":" + old_m + " " + AM_PM;
    if (str.contains("AM")){
        str = str.substring(0,5);
    }else{
        str = str.substring(0,5);
        String[] times = str.split(":");
        String h = times[0];
        String m = times[1];
        int hour = Integer.parseInt(h.toString()) + 12;
        int minutes = Integer.parseInt(m.toString());
        if (hour == 24 && minutes == 00){
            hour = 00;
            minutes = 00;
        }
        str = Integer.toString(hour) + ":" + Integer.toString(minutes) ;
    }

    return str;
}


    public static long parseStandartTime(String str, int offset) {
    String[] temp = str.split(":");
    int h=0;
    if (str.indexOf(":")!=0){
        h = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
    }
    int m=0;
    if (temp.length>1) {
        m = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
    }
    long time = h * MILLIS_IN_HOUR + m * MILLIS_IN_MINUTE;
    long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + offset * DateTimesHelper.MILLIS_IN_DAY;
    currTime = startOfDay(currTime);
    return time + currTime;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы изобретаете велосипед. Делать такое нужно через `SimpleDateFormat` примерно так:

1. Получаем объект `Date` из строки по заданному шаблону:

   ```
   String time = "12:22 AM";
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
   Date dt;
   try {
       dt = sdf.parse(time);
   } catch (ParseException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
2. Теперь можно вывести полученную дату в любом виде через тот же `SimpleDateFormat`:

   ```
   SimpleDateFormat sdf24 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
   String dateIn24h = sdf24.format(dt);
   System.out.println(dateIn24h );
   ```

Comment: а если полученная строка будет String time = " 2: 2 AM", вместо String time = " 2:02 AM", то выйдет ошибка или нет?, просто я в своем коде проверял если ввели не верный формат он приводил его к правильному формату

Comment: @java, с ходу не скажу - надо проверять. Но, думаю, должно нормально отработать.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 3):

Старайтесь сначала искать ответы, потому что зачастую все ваши проблемы уже решены: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531632/conversion-from-12-hours-time-to-24-hours-time-in-java

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
```

Сам код:

```
SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
Date date = parseFormat.parse("10:30 PM");
System.out.println(parseFormat.format(date) + " = " + displayFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: Одной ссылки для ответа мало, согласно правилам сайта. Перенесите код оттуда в ответ)

Comment: Только в Android нет метода `main()` - это может запутать новичков.

Comment: Поправил, оставил голый код.

Comment: Импорты есть смысл вернуть, но отдельным блоком.

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так:

```
String str = "4:39 PM";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date testDate = null;
try {
   testDate = sdf.parse(str);
}catch(Exception ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
 }
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
```